# filter values between -1 and 1 excel

Tags: excel, filter, significance

I have an excel column with some interesting data, but a lot of positive and negative values that are insignificant.

So I would like to turn all the values -1<0<1 into zero.
What would be the best way to do this?

Any help would make my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple `IF` condition for this task.

Assuming you have your data in `column A`, use the below formula in `column B` and drag it down,

```
=IF(AND(A1<=1,A1>=-1),0,A1)
```

[image]

You could later use this column as reference. If you want to ignore `1` and `-1` , then remove the `=` sign within the `AND` function.

```
=IF(AND(A1<1,A1>-1),0,A1)
```